# Applying a circle gradient with imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick, gradient

I want to draw a circular gradient mask on an image, so that the image starts to fade at the outside of the circle with radius R, and fades to white with radius r < R. Is there a way to do this + how?

Example source image: (not the real one I'm trying to work with, but it doesn't matter)

[image]

If I do

```
convert flag1.png -fill white -draw "circle 400,234 200,200" flag2.png
```

then I get this:

[image]

In gimp I an do something like this with a radial gradient in another layer; my attempt looks crappy but this is vaguely what I want, except that it's not a smooth transition at the circle boundary, and my poor hand-eye coordination means I didn't get it centered:

[image]

---

Hmm: I muddled my way (via http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=16692 ) to

```
convert flag1.png -size 800x468 radial-gradient:black-white -compose copy_opacity -composite  flag3.png
```

which gives me something that's close to what I want with r=0 (never really completely fades out except at the very center); is there a way to expand to a white hole that fades out to a larger hole? And what does `-compose copy_opacity -composite` actually do?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you are looking for exactly, but you could experiment with the percentages in this:

```
convert flag.png \( -size 800x468 radial-gradient:black-white -contrast-stretch 60%x0% \) -compose copy_opacity -composite  flag3.png
```

[image]

The part in parentheses makes a black and white circle, and the `-compose copy_opacity -composite` part adopts that black and white circle as the alpha/transparency layer of the original flag image.

The parentheses ensure that the contrast stretch is only applied to the alpha/transparency layer and not the original coloured image.

Comment: ok, I could figure out that's what it did as a whole, but what does `copy-opacity` mean and how do the `-compose` and `-composite` work together?

Comment: thanks; the following does exactly what I was looking for (i'm on Windows hence the quotes): `convert flag1.png "(" -size 800x468 radial-gradient:black-white -contrast-stretch 30%x0% ")" -compose copy_opaci
ty -composite  flag4.png`